# Magento - Hiding words like add to cart and sale from top search keywords

Tags: magento, seo, keyword, google-search

I use Magento 1.7.0.2 and when I use a program to search for the best search keywords on my site (like Woorank), the words "Add to cart" and "Sale" are one of the highest keywords.

Is it possible to hide these words from search engines? I searched a lot on Google, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: Hello check below link may be help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/search-type-like-full-text-or-combined

Answer (score 0):

nopes there is not a way other than not mentioning that keywords in meta

Comment: Do you know that for sure? That they didn't find a solution for this is pretty strange, isn't it?

Comment: yeah i have used magneto recently i also went to the same problem and i didn't found any solution

Comment: But that doesn't say it's impossible. :)